# How can I send mass mailing from Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create a Logic App to mass mailing all my contacts (more than 30K).
Basically I got a very simple flow where I extract contacts from my DB and then I need to send a static email to each of them.

On Logic app I can only find Gmail and Sendgrid ([max 1k according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/#send-email-(v4))) actions but they only allow a limited number of email (generally 1k).
Is there any Action that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email Where is that documentation? can you provide link? you can create a foreach loop inside your Logic App to send your sendgrid requests or just move you sendgrid email code to an Azure Function also you can use Office365. Check in my link the Sendgrid tiers to send emails monthly...

Comment: Thanks @JuanmaFeliu is that scalable considering that I have to send around 30.000 emails ?

Comment: i think you can process 100k iterations and serverless scalability is out of the box in Azure. Refer to Logic App limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#:~:text=For%20logic%20apps%20in%20an%20integration%20service%20environment%2C,60-day-old%20run%20is%20removed%20from%20the%20runs%20history.

Answer (score 1):

Since you extract contacts from DB, so you can separate the contacts to three lists(each list contains 1000 contacts). In each list of contacts, add semicolon between every emaill address by code. Then use a "For each" to loop the "[Send email (V4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/#send-email-(v4))" action of "SendGrid" connector and put each list of contacts into the "**To**" input box of "Send email (V4)" action.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a scalable solution. What when I'll have 1 million contacts?

Comment: Hi @MassimilianoPeluso Since the limit of SendGrid is 1k contacts which we can't break it. I think we can just loop the lists of contacts and send 1000 emails every time. May I know which point do you care about ? The logic app execution time of send email ?